# MySQL multiple LIMIT 1 queries on 1 table

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

- id
- name
- type - enum( A, B, C)
- datetime

The name of the types changes every X days. I want to get the last name and modify date with 1 MySQL query.

So this query:

```
SELECT name, type, datetime 
FROM table WHERE type = A
ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1
```

But then the query must return 3 rows, for every type 1. I tried to do this with an union, but that gave me an error about the order by statement. I can't figure out how to fix this issue.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` int(11) NOT NULL,
`datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
`type` enum('a','b','c') NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by filtering in the `where` clause with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT name, type, datetime 
FROM table t
WHERE datetime = (select max(datetime)
                  from table t2
                  where t.type = t2.type
                 )
```

For each type, the subquery returns the maximum `datetime`.  Rows that match the maximum for their type will be returned.

Comment: Isn't this the same as `GROUP BY`? =/ (i.e.) `SELECT name, type, max(datetime) FROM table GROUP BY type;` and you don't "overload" server with multiple queries

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX . . . I'm not sure what you mean.  If you mean doing a `group by` on the outer query only, then "NO".  Such a query is not guaranteed to get the right name.

Comment: See my updated comment. I gave you an example. It's the same as you are doing with a subquery.

Comment: Like Gordon said, your query can not guarantee to get the right name. See this manual entry: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: @tombom You must be more specific. I can't see the difference. The only one is that if you use this answer, you overload server compared with my example.

Comment: You don't group by name, just by type. So MySQL chooses one of the names of each type group. This may not necessarily be the one where datetime is the greatest. You output max(datetime), but the name may not be the corresponding row.

Comment: I did it with this query:

    SELECT name, type, datetime 
    FROM `table` WHERE id IN (
     SELECT MAX(id) FROM `table` 
     GROUP BY type
    )

Looks to give the correct data - but i'm not sure

Comment: @user2425360 But what do you really want? Last `datetime` for each `type`, last `datetime` from a specific `type` or the lastest `datetime`? You already made different comments/updates and everytime you are changing what do you want to achieve or atleast that is what I see :S

Comment: @tombom You are right, I forgot that `MAX` does not work as `COUNT`, etc. that are specificly made for `GROUP BY` :) Thanks

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX excuse me. I want the last name based on datetime or id for every type.

Comment: @user2425360 Then, the answer given here by Gordon should work.

Comment: @user2425360 . . . And that is exactly what this query does.  I don't see any query in the question (as it now stands) with a `group by`, so I can't comment on that.